# Update table field with data from JSON field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table `order` with fields `sku`, `asin` and json field `raw` with some json data there like:

```
{
   "user_sku": "123",
   "asin": "213213",
}
```

Is that possible to update `order.sku` with data from `order.raw.user_sku` in one sql query?

Comment: where are order.sku, order.raw , order.rwa.user_sku ..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a simple UPDATE

```
update "order"
   set sku = raw ->> 'user_sku';
```

The `->>` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) gets the value for the specified key from the JSON value.